# Keras - How to use ImageDataGenerator without deforming aspect ratio

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I have a folder with images of different sizes. I tried to use ImageDataGenerator with flow_from_directory for batch loading / data augmentation.

Is there a way to keep the aspect ratios of my images ? It seems like the images are being stretched to target_size : I would like to "pad" my images without deforming them (filling the gaps with a constant value)

Here's my code :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    fill_mode='constant')

generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/images',
    target_size=(256,256),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size=99,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False)
```

Images are being stretched to (256,256).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.

There's currently no way to keep aspect ratio when using ImageDataGenerator / flow_from_directory, but a [pull request](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/4987) is opened on Github to add this feature.

Comment: it is still an open pull request: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/pull/81

Comment: still an open pull request

Comment: In my opinion this is just ridiculous! What is even more dumb is that the preprocessing hook runs after the original resize, so you can't even use this to make the images square.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://jdhao.github.io/2017/11/06/resize-image-to-square-with-padding/) you can you use this code to add padding to image without stretching it:

Using`PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

desired_size = 224
im_pth = "/home/jdhao/test.jpg"

im = Image.open(im_pth)
old_size = im.size  # old_size[0] is in (width, height) format

ratio = float(desired_size) / max(old_size)
new_size = tuple([int(x * ratio) for x in old_size])
# use thumbnail() or resize() method to resize the input image

# thumbnail is a in-place operation

# im.thumbnail(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
# create a new image and paste the resized on it

new_im = Image.new("RGB", (desired_size, desired_size))
new_im.paste(im, ((desired_size - new_size[0]) // 2,
                  (desired_size - new_size[1]) // 2))

new_im.show()
```

Using `opencv`:

```
import cv2
desired_size = 224
im_pth = "data_cropped/ges_cropped_0/001019180113990401104712_frame_150.jpg"

im = cv2.imread(im_pth)
old_size = im.shape[:2]  # old_size is in (height, width) format

ratio = float(desired_size) / max(old_size)
new_size = tuple([int(x * ratio) for x in old_size])

# new_size should be in (width, height) format

im = cv2.resize(im, (new_size[1], new_size[0]))

delta_w = desired_size - new_size[1]
delta_h = desired_size - new_size[0]
top, bottom = delta_h // 2, delta_h - (delta_h // 2)
left, right = delta_w // 2, delta_w - (delta_w // 2)

color = [0, 0, 0]
new_im = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                            value=color)

print(new_im.shape)
cv2.imshow("image", new_im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In `ImageDataGenerator` you can use the `preprocessing_function` argument to do the above preprocessing before generating data. I know it's late for the answer, but I hope the other developers might use this code.

Comment: I am not sure if it will make sense to do any kind of resizing and augmentations, because in the documentation, it says "The function will run **after** the image is resized and augmented. So, in your case, the preprocessing_function will be applied on the images whose aspect ratio is already broken

Comment: @KevinSüdmersen that's totally true. I realized that fault after posting this answer but I forgot to update the answer.